# Simultaneously Printing and Writing to a file from cURL and PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to find a better way to phrase this, but what I want is pretty simple (or at least, I think it should be). I want to download a file from a URL (it'll be a binary file around 10MB in size), and I want to stream that to the browser which is requesting it at the same time. As far as I'm aware, that's just the default behavior of php and curl when you don't set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER or CURLOPT_FILE, and according to the documentation, that's because CURLOPT_FILE is set to STDOUT (the page). But what I want is for the server to echo whatever comes from the server as it's being recieved AND to record the output and save it to a file. The latter part doesn't necessarily have to happen while the file is still being downloaded, but it would be nice if that were possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should look up output buffering and [ob_flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) in particular, but be very careful with handling errors!

PHP normally tries to complete execution of all scripts before sending anything to the browser, but if you manually override this, you can incrementally send data to the browser as the script is still running.

Another approach, if you don't want to do it this way, is to use chunked transfers and XMLHttpRequests in an already loaded page, with some kind of server callback that feeds chunks of data to the browser.